# Apex Controller extension to filter records on Visualforce Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

SPARTADMS__Corporate_Document__c is managed package object . Using visualforce page I am able to pull all records from this object . Below is the code :

```
<apex:page standardController="SPARTADMS__Corporate_Document__c" recordSetVar="corpdocs" tabStyle="SPARTADMS__Corporate_Document__c" sidebar="false" showheader="true" >
    <br/><br/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Corporate Document Records">
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!corpdocs}" var="cd">                
                <apex:column headerValue="Corporate Document Id" >
                <apex:outputLink value="/{!cd.ID}">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!cd.ID}"></apex:outputText>
                </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!cd.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!cd.SPARTADMS__Document_Status__c}" />
                <apex:column value="{!cd.SPARTADMS__Status__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!cd.Author__c }"/>                    
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Page Output :

[image]

My requirement is to filter records under column **Document Status** to show only OBSOLETE records.

I have added controller extension ( extensions="extClass" ) to main visualforce page as below :

```
<apex:page standardController="SPARTADMS__Corporate_Document__c" recordSetVar="corpdocs" tabStyle="SPARTADMS__Corporate_Document__c" sidebar="false" showheader="true" extensions="extClass">
    <br/><br/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Corporate Document Records">
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!tList}" var="cd">                
                <apex:column headerValue="Corporate Document Id" >
                <apex:outputLink value="/{!cd.ID}">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!cd.ID}"></apex:outputText>
                </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!cd.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!cd.SPARTADMS__Document_Status__c}" />
                <apex:column value="{!cd.SPARTADMS__Status__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!cd.Author__c }"/>                    
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Related Apex Controller : extClass

```
public class extClass    
    {
        private final SPARTADMS__Corporate_Document__c acct;
        public List<SPARTADMS__Corporate_Document__c> tList  {get;set;}
        public extClass(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) 
        {
            this.acct = (SPARTADMS__Corporate_Document__c)stdController.getRecord();
            tList = [SELECT Name, SPARTADMS__Document_Status__c, Id, SPARTADMS__Status__c, Author__c FROM SPARTADMS__Corporate_Document__c where SPARTADMS__Document_Status__c = 'OBSOLETE' AND ID= :acct.Id];     
        }
    }
```

When I add the apex extension controller to VF page code it throws below error in console :

`Unknown constructor 'extClass.extClass(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)'`

I am quite not sure if my apex controller code is correct . Please suggest what changes I have to make to controller code so error is fixed and on visualforce page only OBSOLETE records are filtered .

Comment: if you have the option in your requirements -- see fcf= URL param to predefine the listview filter which could do the filtering for you without code. [see this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30904/can-you-use-a-listview-filter-with-a-standardsetcontroller-without-a-custom-cont)

Comment: @cropredy Both filterId={filterId} and fcf=URL parameter are working as expected. How can I hard code the url with filterID . When i create visualforce TAB I do not have option to hard code filter ID . Web tab is another option but it shows a embedded page inside the current view . Another solution is to add <apex:selectoption>it shows all listviews to select from , this is not helpful though .

Comment: custom label for the hard-coded filterId ?